# old JOGL, order of transformation

Tags: java, opengl, transformation, jogl, glrotate

I have to solve a problem and I realize it is a bit oldschool code..

I need to write down the order of transformations from 1 to 4 and the result for pruple vertex. Would someone help me check whether it is correct and if not - why?

[image: JOGL code]

It is a bit tough for me to find answers to this and be 100% sure it is correct.

What I think is correct:
1. Start from bottom, take MODELVIEW first, then PROJECTION
- Yet I am not sure I did it right...

EDIT, code rewritten to text:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glTranslatef(-1, -1, -0);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glScalef(2, 1, 3);
gl.glRotatef(-90, 0, 0, 1);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glScalef(2, 3, 1);


gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
gl.glVertex3f(-2, -2, -2);
gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
gl.glVertex3f(2, 1, 3);
gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
gl.glVertex3f(1, 1, -2);
gl.glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
gl.glVertex3f(-1, 1, 2);
gl.glEnd();
```

Write the transformations as they go in order and write the coordinate changes of purple vertex for each transformation.

Transform 1:________________
Coordinates  x:_______  y:_______  z: _______

Transform 2:________________
Coordinates  x:_______  y:_______  z: _______

Transform 3:________________
Coordinates  x:_______  y:_______  z: _______

Transform 4:________________
Coordinates  x:_______  y:_______  z: _______

Comment: General preference here is for the code to be directly in the question (so it's searchable / safe / won't become inaccessible). Mind pulling it in?

Comment: Transformations are applied to vertices in the opposite order of their specification. See for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622381/how-to-calculate-the-shift-parameters-of-gltranslatef-function-in-opengl/25626062#25626062.

Comment: Those kind of task seems really silly to me (besides the prehistoric GL itself). In nitpicking mode, I'd answer that there are only _two_ transforms (based on these matrices) which are applied to the vertex positions after each other in the fixed-function pipeline: the modelview one, and the projection one.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

- supposed to start with model transforms and then projection, always from the bottom
- apply transforms from bottom

Also, I was accidentally using wrong coordinates..

~thanks for help though!